# @Inject applied to a property generates NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm studying "Beginning Java EE 7" by Antonio Goncalves.

The book states there are three ways of applying `@Inject`:
- to an attribute (property)
- to a constructor
- to a method(setter)

When I'm trying the first approach I get a NullPointerException.
I know what a "NullPointerException" means and why this happens. What I can't get is why it is not working with `@Inject`. Do I have to instantiate a type explicitly? What's the point of CDI then?

Here's my code.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class BookService {

    @Inject @ThirteenDigits
    private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

    public Book createBook(String title, Float price, String description){
        Book book = new Book(title, price, description);
        book.setIsbn(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
       return book;
    }
}

@ThirteenDigits
public class IsbnGenerator implements NumberGenerator{

    @Override
    public String generateNumber() {
        return "ISBN";
    }
}
```

Comment: well but Chris already answer! But if you want to know more in your book in the page:38 you have the @Produces. Have a look there :)

Comment: Many thanks for help! But this won't work. A @Produces (according to the book) is helpful when injecting types from jar-files which don't contain beans.xml. And such an annotation isn't applicable when declaring Types (at least that's what my compiler says).

Comment: I see , try this link then and i hope it can help you: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is "never ever post your questions here while you are dumb". 
I mean it, it's hard to admit though. 
In my (this) case I didn't initialize WeldContainer...)

Hence the code above should be accompanied with the following code in a calling class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        BookService bookService = container.instance().select(BookService.class).get();
        weld.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try just add a set method  for numberGenerator

```
public void setNumberGenerator(NumberGenerator numberGenerator){
   this.numberGenerator = numberGenerator;
}
```